# Load items in cart Magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, reorder

I am performing reorder in magento 2. I am able to fetch no of items of a particular order but now I want to move those product into my shopping cart. can anyone please suggest me now what should I do?

```
namespace Racom\Chatbotapi\Model;

use Racom\Chatbotapi\Api\ChatbotapiInterface;

class Chatbotapi implements ChatbotapiInterface
{
    protected $order;
    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

/**
     * Returns the Orders list.
     *
     * @api
     * @param Integer $orderId order Id.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    public function reOrder($orderId) 
    {
        $productCollection = $this->order->load($orderId);

        $orderInformation = $productCollection->getData();

        $value = json_encode($orderInformation);

        return $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reorder functionality is default. So you can check following line. I copied from core controller.

```
/* @var $cart \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart */
$cart = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    try {
        $cart->addOrderItem($item);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        if ($this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getUseNotice(true)) {
            $this->messageManager->addNotice($e->getMessage());
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
}

$cart->save();
```

[Check here Magento 2 default reorder functionality](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/AbstractController/Reorder.php#L55)